# send Mail with javamail and posfix

Tags: jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

I setup a postfix in my OS ubuntu 12.04 and i want to use it for sending a mail with javamail but doesn't work .
The error I'm getting is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: ns303047.xxxxxxx.eu;
```

so this is my main.cf :

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# SASL parameters
# ---------------------------------

# Use Dovecot to authenticate.
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
# Referring to /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
#smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

# SMTPD parameters
# ---------------------------------

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h
# will it be a permanent error or temporary
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
# how long to keep message on queue before return as failed.
# some have 3 days, I have 16 days as I am backup server for some people
# whom go on holiday with their server switched off.
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
# max and min time in seconds between retries if connection failed
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
# how long to wait when servers connect before receiving rest of data
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
# how many address can be used in one message.
# effective stopper to mass spammers, accidental copy in whole address list
# but may restrict intentional mail shots.
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
# how many error before back off.
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
# how many max errors before blocking it.
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12

# This next set are important for determining who can send mail and relay mail
# to other servers. It is very important to get this right - accidentally producing
# an open relay that allows unauthenticated sending of mail is a Very Bad Thing.
#
# You are encouraged to read up on what exactly each of these options accomplish.

# Requirements for the HELO statement
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
# Requirements for the sender details
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
# Requirements for the connecting server
# Attention MODIFICATION de la config proposée.
# ------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Le serveur de blacklist dnsbl.njabl.org n'est plus en service depuis mars 2013 - Voir [[http://www.dnsbl.com/2007/03/how-well-do-various-blacklists-work.html]]
# Donc remplacer la ligne suivante 
# smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
# Par la nouvelle ligne
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl
# Requirement for the recipient address. Note that the entry for
# "check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023" enables Postgrey.
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

# require proper helo at connections
smtpd_helo_required = yes
# waste spammers time before rejecting them
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes

# General host and delivery info
# ----------------------------------

myhostname = ns303047.xxxxxxxxx.eu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = ns303047.xxxxxxxxx.eu, localhost.xxxxxxxxx.eu, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# This specifies where the virtual mailbox folders will be located.
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
# This is for the mailbox location for each user. The domainaliases
# map allows us to make use of Postfix Admin's domain alias feature.
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domainaliases_maps.cf
# and their user id
virtual_uid_maps = static:150
# and group id
virtual_gid_maps = static:1001
# This is for aliases. The domainaliases map allows us to make
# use of Postfix Admin's domain alias feature.
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domainaliases_maps.cf
# This is for domain lookups.
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf

# Integration with other packages
# ---------------------------------------

# Tell postfix to hand off mail to the definition for dovecot in master.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

# Use amavis for virus and spam scanning
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

# Header manipulation
# --------------------------------------

# Getting rid of unwanted headers. See: https://posluns.com/guides/header-removal/
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
# getting rid of x-original-to
enable_original_recipient = no
```

and this is my code java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "ns303047.xxxxxxxxx.eu");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("dak@ns303047.xxxxxxxxx","mypass");
            }
        });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("dev@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +  "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Any pointers or thoughts would help.

Thanks

Comment: The error message looks like the hostname 'ns303047.ip-94-23-204.eu' cannot be resolved to an IP address. Can you try to replace the hostname by its IP (94.23.204.16)?

Maybe a DNS Caching issue as you first tried to resolve the hostname before it got an entry in the DNS. Can you ping the hostname from your development machine?

Comment: i think the problme is not ping i already try it and it works normaly

Comment: Can you telnet to that host? E.g.: ```telnet ns303047.ip-94-23-204.eu 25```. Maybe a firewall (at server or your router / ISP) blocks access to port 25.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to send you an test message, this is what your server says:

```
Trying xx.xx.204.16...
Connected to xxxxx.eu.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 xxxxxx.eu ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
EHLO mail.wf-hosting.de
250-xxxxxxx
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM: <bratkartoffel@stackoverflow.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: dak@xxxxxxx.eu
451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem
```

What says your /var/log/mail.log?

Answer (score 0):

i find that

```
Jun  4 14:20:11 ns303047 postfix/smtpd[15379]: connect from obelix.wf-hosting.de[91.121.90.6]
Jun  4 14:20:58 ns303047 postfix/trivial-rewrite[15384]: warning: do not list domain ns303047.ip-94-23-204.eu in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jun  4 14:20:58 ns303047 postfix/smtpd[15379]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:10023: Connection refused
Jun  4 14:20:58 ns303047 postfix/smtpd[15379]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:10023: Connection refused
Jun  4 14:20:59 ns303047 postfix/smtpd[15379]: warning: connect to 127.0.0.1:10023: Connection refused
Jun  4 14:20:59 ns303047 postfix/smtpd[15379]: warning: problem talking to server 127.0.0.1:10023: Connection refused
Jun  4 14:20:59 ns303047 postfix/smtpd[15379]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from obelix.wf-hosting.de[91.121.90.6]: 451 4.3.5 Server configuration problem; from=<bratkartoffel@stackoverflow.com> to=<dak@ns303047.ip-94-23-204.eu> proto=ESMTP helo=<obelix.wf-hosting.de>
Jun  4 14:21:12 ns303047 postfix/smtpd[15379]: disconnect from obelix.wf-hosting.de[91.121.90.6]
Jun  4 14:24:32 ns303047 postfix/anvil[15381]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:91.121.90.6) at Jun  4 14:20:11
Jun  4 14:24:32 ns303047 postfix/anvil[15381]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:91.121.90.6) at Jun  4 14:20:11
Jun  4 14:24:32 ns303047 postfix/anvil[15381]: statistics: max cache size 1    at Jun  4 14:20:11
```

Comment: You tell postfix in the option "smtpd_recipient_restrictions" that it sould contact 127.0.0.1:10023 for an additional check, but it cannot connect to that port thus failing mail delivery.